# How do I replace my version of node with Homebrew's node?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I have this version of node installed

```
localhost:pplsi.accounts davea$ node -v
v10.16.3
localhost:mydir davea$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

I would prefer to use the homebrew version, so I tried

```
localhost:mydir davea$ brew upgrade node
Updating Homebrew...
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 3 taps (phinze/cask, homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
rabbitmq

Error: node 12.10.0 already installed
```

but still my node shows as the old version

```
localhost:pplsi.accounts davea$ node -v
v10.16.3
```

How do I replace my node with what homebrew installed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably brew installed node is not in path, add /usr/local/bin folder to path and try.

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: "/usr/local/bin" is already in the $PATH.  This returns a value -- "echo $PATH | grep '/usr/local/bin'".  I think the issue is that homebrew doesn't install node there.

Comment: `brew info node` gives you location of where node is installed. you can add that to path. usually brew installs packages in `/usr/local/Cellar/`

Comment: Thx I went ahead and replaced what my /usr/local/bin/node was pointing to with the info from brew info node.